# How can I work around with "Vector smash protection is enabled"?

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, ui-testing

This is a error message that I am getting when I am trying to make a request to a pages (For instance. `http://www.lipsum.com`) that has enabled Vector smash protection. But how can I work around with this ?

This is the exact error message:

> Vector smash protection is enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deal with this problem using the chrome options and creating a desired capabilities but first of all you need to consider:

1: the value you should to put in '`user-data-dir`' is the same you can find out in the route `chrome://version/` in Google Chrome. Let me explain that with a picture (at the end of this answer).

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/Users/YourUser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

​And afterward you need to add this options to your Driver:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

So, this is the best way to make request to a page that has Vector smash protection enabled.

[image: user-data-dir value]